# box2d flash app tutorial

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, box2d

Can anyone kindly provide me with some links for tutorials to guide me to make a flash actionscript 3.0 game through box2d physics. A tutorial guiding through a complete project will be very much helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one looks quiet nice :) Are you using any Engine or pure AS3?

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/introduction-to-box2d-for-flash-and-as3--active-8711

Comment: I am using flash professional cs6. The link is probably based on flash develop. Actually I was looking for something a bit suitable. Thanks for the reply.